# Why is useEffect() not working in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
    if(!token){
        return <Navigate to="/auth/login"/>
    }
    getMe(token)
}, [token, getMe])

return (
    <RootStyle>
        <DashboardNavbar onOpenSidebar={() => setOpen(true)} />
        <DashboardSidebar isOpenSidebar={open} onCloseSidebar={() => setOpen(false)} />
        <MainStyle>
            <Outlet />
        </MainStyle>
    </RootStyle>
);
```

}

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({
    token: auth.token ? auth.token.token : null
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getMe: (token) => dispatch(fetchMe(token)),
})
```

The code above is trying to check if there is token, if not user is redirected to login page else a function that calls  the user object from database runs. The token is a destructured prop.

But the problem is the entire block seems not to be noticed by browser for some reason. When i move the getMe() function outside useEffect is works. debugger isn't even noticed! what could be the problem here?

Running the code below without useEffect will work. But there might be lots of re-renders which might lead to a bug.

```
if(!token){
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login"/>
}
getMe(token)
```

That is why i am wraping all of the above code to useEffect() in such a way that only when the component mounts and if token changes the function getMe() should run.

useEffect is not working at all. even if i just put a console statement

Comment: Is `token` actually changing?

Comment: @ErikAndré everytime the component mounts or token (in the dependency array) changes getMe() function should run. That is what I want.

Comment: @Andy the token might change when expiration time has reached

Comment: @FunStrike if you want getMe() to run on component mount but there is no token, you have a problem, becuase you return from your useEffect if there is no token. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: When I write a simple  useEffect(() => {console.log("sth), []), it won't run, If i pus the same functions outside of useEffect() everithing runs incluiding the check for token and getMe()

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your token has a value and that it really changes to trigger the useEffect? Do a simple console.log of the token at the top of the useEffect.

What is the result of the useEffect right now? Does it navigate to '/auth/login' as if the token was empty? Also, you could post more of your code to let us see the destructuring of your props.

Comment: console.log() inside the useEffect wont work at all?

Comment: i have added alert() debugger() these functions inside are not working at all

Comment: Well, then your useEffect isn't running at all which indicates there is no token or no change in token. console.log or debug the token prop at the top of your component to check its value.

Comment: There token exist. I can console.log() it outside of the useEffect. Besides even when i remove all items in the dependency array it still wont work. The problem is the useEffect() i am using react v18.2.0

Comment: Please post your entire component.

Does your component reach the navigate component and navigate away to 'auth/login'?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a return for useEffect, just `<Navigate to="/auth/login"/>` should work

Comment: I need to return because if there is no token getMe() SHOULD NOT run, that is why I added the return

Comment: Can't you put that inside the else statement?

Comment: I have tried but it is not working either

Comment: My problem here is anything that I put inside useEffect() wont run, whether a console.log() or debugger, etc

Comment: Can you recreate the above issue with any online compiler and provide the link

Comment: There is lots of redux action in the background,

Comment: My problem is why is useEffect() not working in my code. Does it has something to do with my react version?

Comment: Have you tried to console.log() above the if condition. UseEffect will always run once, when component is mounting ( App reload). I can't help without seeing any errors logs.

Comment: Yes but nothing shows up at the browser console

Answer (score 0):

You can do a empty return in your `useEffect`. And when returning the components to render check if the token is set, if not return the `Navigate` component

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!token) return;
  getMe(token);
  // or even
  // if (token) getMe(token);
}, [token, getMe]);

return !token ? (
  <Navigate to="/auth/login" />
) : (
  <RootStyle>
    <DashboardNavbar onOpenSidebar={() => setOpen(true)} />
    <DashboardSidebar
      isOpenSidebar={open}
      onCloseSidebar={() => setOpen(false)}
    />
    <MainStyle>
      <Outlet />
    </MainStyle>
  </RootStyle>
);
```

Comment: getMe(token) wont run

Comment: You could add a more explicit if statement like `if (token === null) return`